# How to set compiler options from config with cmake in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, configuration

I want to pass some parameters to compiler (`-W...`, `-D...`) but I don't want to define them in `CMakeLists.txt` but from visual studio's interface instead. In general I don't want to edit any code and configs in the project
I've seen some properties might be related to my need in `CMakeSettings.json`: `cmakeCommandArgs` which is responsible for options during configuration phase of cmake, `buildCommandArgs` which is responsible for options to build system (ninja in my case) and `ctestCommandArgs` which I don't even use
I tried to use `"variables"` field as that:

```
"variables": [
   "name": "_SILENCE_TR1_NAMESPACE_DEPRECATION_WARNING",
   "value": "1"
]
```

but it didn't gave me expected result and hadn't seen that definition in the call to my compiler in output window
I also tried that" `"cmakeCommandArgs": "-D_SILENCE_TR1_NAMESPACE_DEPRECATION_WARNING:BOOL=ON"` - no luck

Comment: `-D` option to `cmake` defines **CMake variable**, not a macro definition for C/C++ code. It is project itself (its `CMakeLists.txt`) which could create macro definition for code according to the variable's value. From the command line you may set `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variable, which is eventually passed to the compiler. But value of this variable should include also basic settings. Possible workflow: 1. Run project's configuration without additional settings. 2. Inspect value of `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variable. 3. Copy that value to your one and append what you need.

Comment: @Tsyvarev It is not good approach IMO. The project can have different conditional configurations, it will be only valid for a single time but not on a permanent basis

Comment: Yes, value of `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variable is configuration dependent (and could be even machine-dependent). But CMake provides no other mechanisms for set compiler flags outside of a project and a toolchain.

Comment: Did you try instead setting the variable `-D_SILENCE_TR1_NAMESPACE_DEPRECATION_WARNING` in the `buildCommandArgs` section?